# Call function multiple times with a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a function which produces a map, which I will turn into a gif by plotting 24 versions of the map representing the 24 hours in a day. I can call my map the following way.

```
get_gif(0.0, '00:00:00', '00.png')
```

to print the next map I will call the following:

```
get_gif(1.0, '01:00:00', '01.png')
```

And so on until up to my final call which will look like this:

```
get_gif(23.0, '23:00:00', '23.png')
```

How would I make a loop so that I can make all 24 calls in one go? My first argument is a float between `0.0` to `23.0` (the hours of the day), then a string for the time which I am printing in the map, then another string which is the file name.

Comment: This could be accomplished several ways (f strings, string.format(), string concatenation), what have you tried so far based on your own research?

Comment: Try reading about the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function and about [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: Speaking as someone who did _not_ downvote: Nobody is downvoting for asking a question, however many people will downvote questions that show no effort to solve the problem before asking since this is not a code-writing or tutorial site

Comment: I apologise for jumping to conclusions. Next time I will put more effort into the nature by which I ask questions.

Comment: One useful resource is the help article on creating a [mcve] to make it easier for us to help you better

Comment: @G.Anderson that's great thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python3.6 and above:

```
for hour in range(24):
    get_gif(float(hour), f"{hour:02}:00:00", f"{hour:02}.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a string formatter. In python that would be something like

```
'{0}.png'.format(n)
```

In python the '{0}'.format(n) will replace the {0} with the number n. The variable n can be updated with a for loop. Unfortunately it seems that your file contain things like '01.png' so you cannot do

```
'{0}.png'.format(1)
```

Because the name will become 1.png. For this reason you can use an if clause and use

```
'0{0}.png'.format(n)
```

If n is smaller then 10.

Comment: Or, instead of an `if` check, use format specifiers: `'{0:02}.png'.format(n)`. This will make sure the number is always 2-digits, zero padded if needed